# Indexing CVS Repository

Tags: cvs

Are there any tools available that will index a CVS repository?

Basically what I would like to do is run a daily scheduled job that will index CVS repository file names and contents and puts that information into a database.  We could write such a tool, but naturally it would be better if there is something already available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, [Fisheye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/), formerly of Cenqua, now owned by Atlassian (of JIRA fame).

It is commercial software, but it's also rather tasty.